# Angular 7 setting selected value not firing change event

Tags: angular7

I have one single selection drop down and multi select drop down. Both is having dynamic value.

What I am doing is the I am clicking on edit button it shows modal inside modal there is select drop-downs of module and multi select of actions.

I am dynamically selecting module name it works perfectly but dependent multi-select is not working. I think single select is not firing change event.

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <label for="module">Select Module</label>
    <select class="form-control" (change)="onChangeModuleDD($event)" name="moduleSelection" required>
    <option value="">-- Select Module --</option>
    <option *ngFor="let module of allModuleData" [value]="module | json" [selected]="module.name == usermodule">{{
        module.name
        }}</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="col-md-12">
    <label for="actions">Select Actions/Charts</label>
    <ng-multiselect-dropdown [placeholder]="'-- Select Action/Charts --'" [data]="dropdownList" [settings]="dropdownSettings"
        (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)" name="actionSelection" (onDeSelect)="OnItemDeSelect($event)"
        (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)" (onDeSelectAll)="onDeSelectAll($event)">
    </ng-multiselect-dropdown>
</div>
```

COMPONENT:

```
onChangeModuleDD(event) {
    this.selectedItems = [] // empty selected action array
    this.dropdownList = []
    let value = event.target.value

    if (value) {
      let parsedValue = JSON.parse(value)
      this.usermodule = parsedValue.name

      if (parsedValue.hasCRUD == 0) {
        this.userListingApi.fetchAllDashboardAction().subscribe(res => {
          this.dropdownList = []
          for (let i = 0; i < res['data'].length; i++) {
            this.dropdownList.push(res['data'][i])
          }
        })
      } else {
        this.userListingApi.fetchAllCRUDAction().subscribe(res => {
          this.dropdownList = []
          for (let i = 0; i < res['data'].length; i++) {
            this.dropdownList.push(res['data'][i])
          }
        })
      }
    } else {
      console.log('Nothing to display')
    }
  }
```

At the time of insertion it is working perfectly but when I select dynamically it is not working.

EDIT:

```
onItemSelect(item: any) {
    this.selectedItems.push(item)
}

OnItemDeSelect(items: any) {
    var id = items._id
    this.selectedItems = this.selectedItems.filter((item) => item['_id'] !== id);
  }

onDeSelectAll(items: any) {
    this.selectedItems = items
  }
```

Comment: Usually when you have a dropdown, and its events fire OK, and then you recreate its items, and events suddenly stop firing, it means your newly created items don't have event handlers (you've erased them).

Comment: @SergeyKirienko So how can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

in your component I cant see onItemSelect($event),OnItemDeSelect($event) and other multi select method bind to the event.

check this link :
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-multiselect-dropdown

add this in your component and try:

```
 onItemSelect(item: any) {
 console.log(item);
 }
```

Comment: I have added still no luck

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is even supposed to work. Please look at this issue: https://github.com/NileshPatel17/ng-multiselect-dropdown/issues/5.

Probably events get erased after reloading `[data]` (see my comment).

Comment: where is your comment ?

Comment: @MysteriousCoder, it is under your question

Comment: is it possible ?

Comment: Not until this component is fixed by its creator or someone.